# Use substring for every element of Hashtable JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm working on my first project in JSP. I have a istance of Hashtable (hParamsRecherche) that get some values from a form.

I have to substring every element of this Hashtable :

```
 hParamsRecherche.get("INVERSE_GEO").toString()
```

That contains values like:

```
'95','14','300','165'
```

I have to substring all the element that have a length bigger than 2 char, et take the first two number.

```
    '95','14','30','16'
```

I think that i have to do this with a loop, but i m open to others suggestions ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process all strings in way that they are at most 2 digits long, you can use the following approach.

It uses [streams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams-introduction) instead of a loop, which is more elegant solution, because it uses less lines of code to solve the same problem as a loop, without sacrificing code readability.

```
// ... contains a list like '95','764', etc .. 
// getListOfStrings() is the method, which wraps  hParamsRecherche.get
var stringsToCut = getListOfString()

// The result variable now contains the list of strings, which are at most 2 digits long
var result = stringsToCut.stream
.map(s -> s.length() <= 2 ? s :s.substring(0,2))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```